# Send and read the SMS content sent via native SMS app in Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sms, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic/Cordova app. From my application, user can click on a phone number in order to send SMS. When click on that number, native SMS app will open and then user can type his/her own SMS and send the SMS. Is there any way, from my app I can get the SMS content?

Answer (score 8):

As you are using ionic/cordova, a SMS plugin is required to do such work.

Besides jsmobile SMS plugin, there is another one with more APIs:
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.rjfun.cordova.sms

As mentioned in the description:

```
sendSMS(address(s), text, successCallback, failureCallback);
listSMS(filter, successCallback, failureCallback);
deleteSMS(filter, successCallback, failureCallback);

startWatch(successCallback, failureCallback);
stopWatch(successCallback, failureCallback);

enableIntercept(on_off, successCallback, failureCallback);
restoreSMS(msg_or_msgs, successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Events

```
'onSMSArrive'
```

You can get the SMS content in either of the following ways:

1. implement the UI, get user's input, and call plugin's API to send the SMS.

Or,

2. let the default SMS app send the message, then read the SMS from the sent box.

BTW, the plugin works for Android only, FYI.

Comment: the link to the plugin is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sms)

Comment: also be aware that this plugin is not free to use for some cases. check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35408486/3883957) if you need MIT based plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There is [cordova-plugin-sms](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms) option, as @MikeX suggested, but notice that its license is not free use.

So I chose using [Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin](https://github.com/sidchilling/Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin), which is MIT license.

and then it just

```
 var smsInboxPlugin = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/smsinboxplugin');
  smsInboxPlugin.startReception (function(msg) {
     alert(msg);
     stopReadingSMS(smsInboxPlugin);
   }, function() {
     alert("Error while receiving messages");
     stopReadingSMS(smsInboxPlugin);
   });

function stopReadingSMS(smsInboxPlugin) {
    smsInboxPlugin.stopReception (function() {
        console.log("Correctly stopped SMS receiver");
    }, function() {
        console.log("Error while stopping the SMS receiver");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to know what the user typed in another app? If so, I don't believe you can. In theory you can try skipping the real SMS app and using a plugin: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.jsmobile.plugins.sms

Comment: I saw that plugin. But it sends a predefined content but I would like, user will type his/her own sms and click send from native sms app. Is there any event related to this operation (sendsmsbuttonclick?) something like "endcallbutton"?

Comment: It doesn't send predefined content. The text message can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there are ionic wrappers for cordova extensions. You can use $cordovaSMS ([docs here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sms/))

```
module.controller('ThisCtrl', function($cordovaSms) {

 document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    $cordovaSms
      .send('phonenumber', 'SMS content', options)
      .then(function() {
        // Success! SMS was sent
      }, function(error) {
        // An error occurred
      });

  });

});
```

To see what the user is typing you can have them write the 'SMS content' inside your app. One you leave your app I don't think you can grab text from the native SMS field

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use sms: url for opening native sms app for that you need to add
<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/> inside config.xml
```

after adding above line use sms link as follows

```
<a class="button icon-left ion-android-mail button-balanced button-outline" href="sms:9808350855">SMS</a>
```