# Web application sms reading using cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I m making a todo list web application. I will compile it on emulator using geny motion, I want to know can I add a fuctionality that my app reads sms on the mobile and the look for pending bills and add to the todolist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573172/send-and-read-the-sms-content-sent-via-native-sms-app-cordova